# 404 not found while writing .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having some issues with my .htaccess - I am trying to make my URL's more friendly. I have a category.php with only 1 parameter - category.php?cat=.... When I try to load it like localhost/category.php?cat=Accommodation for instance, it'll get the information that is needed. However, when I go to localhost/category/Accommodation, it returns as 404 not found.

AllowOverride All is on in httpd.conf, and mod_rewrite is enabled. I have searched all over for similar questions but was unable to come up with anything.

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+) category.php?cat=$1 [NC]
```

I tried several solutions posted on SO, however they didn't fix my 404 issue.

Comment: Where is that configuration file stored, is it _really_ readable by the http server, have you restarted the http server after having made changes to the central configuration? Does you setup contain any _other_ rewrite rules? What does your http server's error log file contain? Did you _really_ test using a fresh, anonymous browser window or clear your browser cache? And finally, if nothing helps, you need to enable rewrite logging to understand what is going on.

Comment: Is the 404 response generated by Apache or your application? What happens when you call `category.php` without the `cat` URL parameter?